# Line width of plotted data in \tikz \datavisualization

Tags: width, tikz-datavisualization, line

Does anybody know how to set line-width of plotted
data using command `data[]{}` in the command 
`\tikz \datavisualization`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly modifying an example from section 78.2.3 *Styling a Visualizer* in the manual:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization,datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
\tikz \datavisualization
[scientific axes=clean,
visualize as smooth line/.list={sin},
sin={style={red,line width=4pt}} %%% <--- style of lines in sin set defined here
]

data [set=sin, format=function] {
var x : interval[0:3*pi];
func y = sin(\value x r);
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible to set width in e.g. points. Like `style={thickness=4pt}`?

Comment: @Joseph Same as usual with TikZ: `line width=4pt`